# RTSP stream failed in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera

Im trying to use `OpenCV 2.4.8` for reading RTSP h.264 stream from IP-camera:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture("rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.168:80/ch0_0.264");

    if(!capture.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("Frame");

    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if(capture.read(frame))
        {
            std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
            cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
            if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

First 670-700 frames (25-30 seconds of the stream) well captured, but further `capture.read(frame)` ALWAYS returns `false` (frames not grabbed). How to fix this problem?

Comment: does it work with VLC?

Comment: @Micka, yes, in VLC works.